# How to validate mobile number in mobile devices in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function validateInput(evt) 
{
        var e = window.event || evt; 
        if (e.keyCode > 31 && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57))
        {
        document.getElementById('mno').value="";   
        document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="yellow";
        return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="white";
        return true;
    }
```

This is code for input mobile field validation. Its not working in mobile devices.
Only using JavaScript, without using jQuery/others' scripting please!

Comment: This is not a good way. You should validate the whole text. Anyways I don't understand why did you put that `e.keyCode > 31`

Comment: Yes you are right pal. I want your suggestion. What is the best way to get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use regular expressions:

```
function validateInput(evt) 
{
        var pattern = /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;
        var e = window.event || evt; 
        if (pattern.match(e.keycode))
        {
        document.getElementById('mno').value="";   
        document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="yellow";
        return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="white";
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT:

You asked for a better way. The better way is to attach `keypress` event to your text field and perform validation on the whole string instead of validating character by character.

Comment: I was going to suggest this. Points up to you sir

Comment: error : line 5 "if cond is not closed"
javascript is case sensitive as well.
it through's Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
using following code:
<form>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateInput(event)" id="mno"/>
</form>

Comment: that's because of the unclosed parenthesis change to `if (pattern.match(e.keycode))`

Comment: The code is not working in mobile devices. You are right in your own context but that's not what the question suggest. The question is to code a javascript code for validating mobile number field in a form in mobile devices using XHTML. If this is possible else give an alternative solution using javascript and XHTML.

Comment: There is no such thing as `regular expressions` do not work on mobile devices. To know more where the problem is occurring, please share how you are calling this function and its respective html markup

Answer (score 0):

This is a starting point to your problem using jQuery:

```
$("#mno").on("keypress",function(evt){
  validateInput(evt);
});



function validateInput(evt) 
{
    var e = window.event || evt; 
    if (e.keyCode > 31 && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57))
    {
    $('#mno').val("");   
    $('#mno').css({"backgroundColor":"yellow"});
    return false;
    }
    $('#mno').css({"backgroundColor":"white"});
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jyvt9/

Of course this is limited to manage only number input and not include mobile phone number validation

Comment: The example code is not fully correct . It holds' single value with wrong input.For wrong input's it should be blank/null.

Answer (score 0):

First, fixing your function:

```
function validateInput(evt) 
{
    var e = window.event || evt; 
    if (e.charCode< 48 || e.charCode> 57)
    {
    document.getElementById('mno').value="";   
    document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="yellow";
    return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="white";
    return true;
}
```

This is just a fix for the what you have.

Comment: ok.ping me if you find the solution. Is it even possible to use javascript with these event? I am not sure for javascript doing this task. The reason is mobile devices has touch/keypad type of keyboad and a single key is used for various key events in keypad type mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateInput(evt) 
{
    var e = window.event || evt; 
    if (e.charCode< 48 || e.charCode> 57)
    {
    document.getElementById('mno').value="";   
    document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="yellow";
    return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('mno').style.backgoundColor="white";
    return true;
}

</script>
<!--
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="tel" onkeypress="return validateInput(this)" id="mno" pattern="[0-9]{10}" maxlength="10" minlength="10"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will work with all mobile devices. Thank you for your kind replies.